# Add WordPress wysiwyg/tiny mce editor on an image attachment details

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Right now I have this snippet of code, and can add an input on the attachment details of an image. But I don't know how to add a wysiwyg/tinymce editor like the one in the widgets: https://gyazo.com/d40dad527f9d7b52f112b6884aac009c. Am I going to have to add some javascript in the admin.js to turn this textarea into a tinymce editor?

```
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', [self::class, 'test'], 10, 2 );

function test($fields, $post) {
        $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'buy_now', true );
            $fields['test'] = array(
                    'label' =>  __( 'Test', 'text-domain' ),
                    'input' => 'textarea',
                    'value' => $meta,
                    'show_in_edit' => true,
            );



            return $fields; 
    }
```